# Questions about the position of a matrix and a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I got quite confused by position of a matrix and a vector.

For example, the definition of a range space put a matrix in front of a vector, like $R(A) = \{ Ax | x∈ R^n \}$; However for a linear transform $T: V^n -> V^n$, A can be a matrix representing T that is $T(x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n) = (x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n) A$ where {$x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n$} is a set of basis of $V^n$ and here A is following a vector matrix; besides, if {$y_1, y_2, ..., y_n$} is a set of basis of $V^n$ and {$z_1,z_2, ..., z_n$} is a set of another, the transition matrix C from basis $z$ to basis $y$ is always defined on some books as $y = zC$.

I mean why does matrix A was sometimes put on a vector's left and other on right?

Comment: Would you please clarify your question? I would like to help but at the present stage I cannot even make head or tail of the target. And I do not even know what the points that confuse me are.

Comment: @Chou: Thanks. Generally, I want to know when to put a matrix in front of a vector and when to put it after (I think when matrix A is on right, the x seems to be a matrix of vectors instead of a single vector).